# Applying pigeonhole principle to determine whether a list of strings must have duplicates.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Say you have a program that creates strings of lower-case letters of length 5 or less. It is told that the program holds 600,000 words on its drive. How can you figure out if all the words are distinct? And the minimal number of words w/o duplicates?

We are told to use the PHP, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it.

Comment: Yes, basically how to figure out if all words can be distinct

Comment: If we allow the "empty" word the number of words of length $\le 5$ is $1+26^1+26^2+\cdots +26^5$. Calculate or estimate, and compare with $600000$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas is that for part 2?

Comment: For the first part. For the second, I don't like the wording, the minimal number of words without duplicates is $0$. Presumably one wants the minimal number of duplicates.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the minimal number of words that guarantee there are no duplicates

Comment: And oh ok, so if the estimate of 1 + 26 etc etc is greater than 600,000, that means that all words are distinct?

Comment: $1 + 26 + \cdots + 26^5 = 12,356,631$ is the size of the complete dictionary of all words of length five or less. So, it is possible that all the words are distinct, but it is also possible that they are not (maybe the drive holds the same word 600,000 times). I don't think pigeonhole can help you any further here. It sounds like you need to write a program that compares the strings.

Comment: EDITED: @AndréNicolas so I can't edit my earlier comment, but I meant to say minimum number of words that will guarantee there will be duplicates, my bad

Comment: The empty word is probably not being counted as a word.  Since there are $26+26^2+\cdots+26^5$ words, one more will guarantee there is at least one duplicate.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok, so for example, if it were less than 600,000, there would be guaranteed duplicates for sure right?

Comment: Already $26^5$ is much bigger than $600000$. So it is perfectly possible that all the $600000$ words are distinct. Yes, if our sum were less than $600000$ there would be guaranteed duplicates. But the sum is bigger, not less.